# C++: resize must be in class/structure/union

Tags: c++, windows, class

I have

```
struct udtJoinFeatures
{
    double Values[16];
};
```

Now when I want to do the following...

```
void clsMapping::FeedJoinFeaturesFromMap(udtJoinFeatures &uJoinFeatures)
{
    uJoinFeatures.Values.resize(16);
    memcpy(&uJoinFeatures.Values[0], &((char*)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos],iByteCount);
}
```

... the compiler tells me "Left from .resize there needs to be a class/structure/union".

Does anybody see where I went wrong and how I can make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: What is `Values`? (Not a **class/structure/union**).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call `resize` on array. Use `vector` instead.

```
vector<double> Values;
```

However, I don't see why you would call resize on the array to resize it to the same number of the elements.

Comment: Doh, I overlooked that the array is already sized! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `Values` is a built-in array. Built-in arrays have a fixed size in C++. If you want to use a variable size for your array, you need to use a suitable class type, probably `std::vector<double>`:

```
struct udtJoinFeatures
{
    std::vector<double> Values = std::vector<double>(16);
};
```

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, just noticed. ... and `(16)` can't be used!

Comment: @juanchopanza: This isn't quite scalable: I'd think the assignment notation would work better in this case which I still don't quite like as it requires retyping the type or use `decltype(Values)` which would be obfuscation of intent.

Comment: I had typed too fast. I think this is the best one can do, unfortunately (although one could use `{}` instead of assignment notation, but that is just a detail. It is a shame vectors of numeric types don't play so well with uniform initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call method `resize` on an array.

I suggest you to use a container like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which allows you to do that:

```
std::vector<double> Values;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about vectors - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/. Then use

```
typedef std::vector<double> udtJoinFeatures;

void clsMapping::FeedJoinFeaturesFromMap(udtJoinFeatures &x) {
   x.clear();
   x.resize(m_pVoiceData.size());
   x = m_pVoiceData;
}
```